# Rails Layout deprecation warning: What is being deprecated, why, and what is the better pattern to follow in the future?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I understand the literal text of this error message I'm getting from Rails 3.2.13, but I don't understand the motivation behind it or what is the best practice for cleaning this up.

> DEPRECATION WARNING: Layout found at "admin/admin" for Admin::AdminController but parent controller set layout to "admin/admin". Please explicitly set your layout to "admin/admin" or set it to nil to force a dynamic lookup.

I read the [deprecation warnings when running specs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8992831/712765) question and answers, but the answers suggest two different solutions and lack a thorough explanation of this history and future of this capability enough to guide me on what is the best thing for me to do in general.

For example, it's not clear to me if what is being deprecated is allowing the parent controller to override the default layout or what is being deprecated is allowing the default layout to override what is set in the parent controller.  I also don't understand the motivation for the change in behavior and how that can guide me to improving the architecture of my application.

Would someone please clue me in.

Comment: Seems like a bug in Rails... I'll try to find this in the source code, and see if there is any explanation on why this is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so i found this message in the rails source code. It turns out that the layout option is not inheritable in Rails 3.2.13 (should be fixed in newer versions of rails). This means that child controllers would (unexpectedly) try to find a layout file dynamically, that is a file that with the same name as the controller, in the layout director.

In your case it found one "admin/admin" and uses this file. This happens to be the same file you specified in the parent controller, but lets say that you have specified something else in the parent controller. In that case is it nice to know that what you specified in the parent controller isn't used in the child controller. That's why it's warning you, as this behaviour will change in future versions.

So in conclusion it's the "allowing the default layout to override what is set in the parent controller" that would be changed in future versions, and you could set the layout to both `nil` or `admin/admin`, both solution would be fine, but the last is what Rails will do in future version, by inhering from the parent controller.

Hope this helps. You can find the message here in the source code: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.14/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/layouts.rb#L308-L328.

Comment: Wow, this still doesn't make sense to me.  I want the child to inherit the parent layout, but both options (setting it to `nil` or `admin/admin`) prevent that from happening in future Rails.  Do you know if this future rails where inheriting from the parent is the default is a 3.x version or is it 4.0?

Comment: That's right but the problem is that, that isn't possible now, so not setting the admin to either `nil` or `admin/admin` will change the layout in future versions. Looking at the Rails guide does it actually looks like it's deprecated and changed already from Rails 3.2. I can understand if you'r confused now, i am at least :D! I can't find anything else on the subject, however the deprecation warning is removed in Rails 4.